# JQuery AJAX 'post' data isn't making it through to the web api controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm setting a Person() object to a couple of ko.observables and trying to pass it into my ajax call.  On the other side, a web API controller its coming over as null.

This is how I'm data-binding to the ko.observables:

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" data-bind="text: firstname">

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" data-bind="text: lastname">

<label>Email Address <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" data-bind="text: email">
```

my .js that is suppose to pick up the ko.observable values but isn't:

```
var firstname = ko.observable();
var lastname = ko.observable();
var email = ko.observable();
var password = ko.observable();


function submitclicked() {
    insertNewUser();

    ko.applyBindings(firstname);
    ko.applyBindings(lastname);
    ko.applyBindings(email);
    ko.applyBindings(password);
};

function Person() {
    this.FirstName = firstname();
    this.LastName = lastname();
    this.Email = email();
    this.Password = password();
}

function insertNewUser() {

var person = new Person();

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Reg",
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(person),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
    person(result);
    }
})
```

My controller which is somehow not pulling in that "person" object properly.  it gets the objects but all of the values are null (even though the text inputs do have text)
First_Name = null, Last_Name = null, Email = null, Password = null

```
public void addUser(Person item)
{
    var db = new MyEntities();

    try
    {
    User record = new User()
    {
        First_Name = item.FirstName,
        Last_Name = item.LastName,
        Email = item.Email,
        Password = item.Password
    };
    db.User.Add(record);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Anyone notice where I've messed it up?

EDIT: cleaned up the example a bit.

Comment: do you have frompost in the method

Comment: If you haven't tried this, fire the same request and data to your controller using Fiddler or Postman to eliminate any potential problem with your Web API code. Once you know the request is coming through correctly this way, then you can concentrate on what's different with the request from your JS layer.

Comment: Also, when using IO resources like a database or file, it's good practice (some say mandatory) to use a `using` syntax, e.g. `using (var db = new MyEntities()) { ... }`, so that the database object is correctly disposed at the closing brace.

Comment: @dijkay No, best practice is to let a DI framework lifetime manage the Context for the entire duration of the request. This way you benefit from caching

Answer (score 1):

```
  public ..... Post([FromBody]objClass obj)
  var thing=obj.property;
```

Also you cant post an object (it needs to be real data) , see Json stringify try this    thread [How to JSON.stringify and JSON.parse without getting an empty object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493048/how-to-json-stringify-and-json-parse-without-getting-an-empty-object)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ko.toJSON` it will correctly serialize the observables to plain JSON data

Also you model definition is strange. To define the observables outside of the constructor, this mean that you cant have more than one instance of the Person object

Comment: changing the var's from var firstname = ko.observable(); to ko.toJSON(); didn't appear to change anything.  When I get into my controller the Person object still has null for all of the values.

Comment: You also need to decorate method argument with [FromBody]