# Knockout data-bind:text not getting picked up in Function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

New to Knockout.js and am having an issue picking up the text input data.  My form has these fields on it with data-bind:text:

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" 
       data-bind="text: firstname">

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" 
       data-bind="text: lastname">

<label>Email Address <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" 
       data-bind="text: email">
```

In my .js page I'm unsure if I should be declaring the firstname, lastname, email.... inside or ousitde of the the Person function.  I've tried both ways and the var's are always null.  I can't seem to get them to pickup the value in the text boxes. There is a submit button on the form that kicks off the function.

```
function submitclicked() {
    insertNewUser();

    ko.applyBindings(firstname);
    ko.applyBindings(lastname);
    ko.applyBindings(email);
    ko.applyBindings(password);
};

function Person() {
    var firstname = ko.toJSON();
    var lastname = ko.toJSON();
    var email = ko.toJSON();
    var password = ko.toJSON();

    this.FirstName = firstname;
    this.LastName = lastname;
    this.Email = email;
    this.Password = password;
}

function insertNewUser() {

    var person = new Person();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Reg",
        type: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(person),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            person(result);
        }
    })
};
```

Any ideas where I'm off?  Thanks.

Comment: There is not even a single line correct in your code... You are missusing `ko.applyBindings` and mix up `ko.observable` and `ko.toJSON` etc... please check out the great examples and documentation on the KO website: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/ and http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Comment: How do you nominate a comment for comment of the year?

Comment: @nemesv I changed from ko.observable to ko.toJSON based on this feedback http://stackoverflow.com/a/24642492/1245546.  If the ko.applyBindings in my submitclicked() (in the code above) aren't correct, can you offer any advice as to where I should relocate them to?

Comment: Thats not what I said. I told you to use ko.toJSON instead of JSON.stringify.

Comment: Here is a example on how to declare a viewmodel correctly. I even throw in a computed declaration as a bonus http://jsfiddle.net/YfxK3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's recommended in this case to just create one viewmodel and apply bindings once. In other words you should be applying bindings once to person.

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new Person());
});
```

There is no need to call ko.toJSON() unless you want to convert a knockout model to json. You also need to use ko.observable() for anything that you want to be updated in the model when the form changes.

The other problem is in your model you are using Uppercase when in your view you are using lowercase. ie Firstname vs firstname. It's also recommended to use self to help with scoping.

```
function Person() {
    var self = this;

    self.firstname = ko.observable();
    self.lastname = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();
};
```

Then to insert the user, you would insert the person from the model itself using a function on the model:

```
self.insert = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Reg",
        type: 'post',
        data: ko.toJSON(self),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            person(result);
        }
    });
}
```

You should then use the click binding to link the insert to a button:

```
<button data-bind="click: insert">Add</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjcmR/2/